# stop echo for print codeigniter form function

Tags: php, codeigniter, echo

i am working on codeigniter.
and i have one harder challenge to stop using echo.
like i am follow codeigniter syntax .

```
echo form_hidden('urlEvent', $urlEvent, ' id = "urlEvent"');
echo form_label('Event URL');
if (strpos($urlEvent, 'www.hkrunners.com')!==false) {
    echo "<p>";
    if (!isset($startDate)) 
        $startDate='';
    echo form_label('Start Date');
    echo form_input('startDate', $startDate, ' id = "event_date" class="text small"');
    echo "</p>";
    echo "<p>";
    if (!isset($endDate)) 
        $endDate='';
    echo form_label('End Date');
    echo form_input('endDate', $endDate, ' id = "event_time" class="text small"');
    echo "</p>";
}
```

any way to pint show this hidden box without using echo in php.
tahnks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to user codeigniter form function you can simplely uer generel html format

like

```
   <input type="hidden" name="urlEvent" id="urlEvent" value = <?php echo
    $urlEvent;?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set hidden fields in `form_open` function

Like this

```
  <?php echo form_open($action, array("method" => "post"), 
              array("hiddenField1" => "value1", "hiddenField2" => "value2")); ?>
    <!-- form other fields -->
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```